# uploading doc and docx file in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

hello all i am getting trouble to upload a doc and docx file in codeigniter.
i checked mime type in config/mime.php.
can any one tell me that what's problem is there?
following is my mime.php file.

```
'doc'   =>  'application/msword',
'docx'  =>  array('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document', 'application/zip'),
'xlsx'  =>  array('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', 'application/zip'),
'word'  =>  array('application/msword', 'application/octet-stream'),
```

Comment: what is the trouble?? are you getting any error??

Comment: yes sir..
The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.

Comment: when i echo the type of file it returns 
application/octet-stream

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this `system/libraries/Upload.php` line number 199, in codeigniter 3(its 455)

```
$this->_file_mime_type($_FILES[$field]);
```

Change that line to:

```
$this->_file_mime_type($_FILES[$field]); var_dump($this->file_type); die();
```

whatever come in `var_dump()` add that to your `mimes.php`.

Comment: it returns
 string(24) "application/octet-stream"

Comment: add `application/octet-stream` in mimes.php

Comment: it already there sir..
'word'  =>  array('application/msword', 'application/octet-stream'),

Comment: add that for `doc` and `docx`.

Comment: ok thanks Niranjan sir...
it works after appending application/octet-stream to doc&docx type