# doc and docx file upload on codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I want to upload file type `.doc` and `.docx` in codeigniter with updated version but a message is coming all the time **The file type is not allowed here**.

I have searched many times but i could not find any suitable answer.

also i have changed mime file on `application/config/mime.php`

```
'doc'  => array('application/msword', 'application/octet-stream','application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text'),
'docx' => array('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document', 'application/zip'),
```

please advise how to solve this problem.

Comment: So, if anyone know please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [uploading doc and docx file in codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33889501/uploading-doc-and-docx-file-in-codeigniter)

Comment: append  application/octet-stream to doc & docx type

Comment: added but still have isssue